# CDF custom Plugin on DataProc - Provider for class javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory cannot be created

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion, dataproc, cdap

To set the context, I have created a custom `CDAP` transform plugin and tested it in `CDAP` local successfully. However when I deploy it to `GCP CDF` instance, everything works fine till preview mode but the actual problem occurs when I run the pipeline on `Dataproc` cluster. With that said, `CDAP` custom plugin work well with CDAP native mode but throwing below exception when it is executed on `Dataproc`. I could not move forward as I keep getting the same error even after multiple attempts.

```
2024-03-06 10:58:28,123 - ERROR [SparkRunner-phase-1:i.c.c.i.a.r.ProgramControllerServiceAdapter@98] - Spark Program 'phase-1' failed.
java.lang.Exception: javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider for class javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory cannot be created
    at io.cdap.cdap.app.runtime.spark.SparkRuntimeService.startUp(SparkRuntimeService.java:389)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutionThreadService$1$1.run(AbstractExecutionThreadService.java:47)
    at io.cdap.cdap.app.runtime.spark.SparkRuntimeService.lambda$null$2(SparkRuntimeService.java:525)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider for class javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory cannot be created
    at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.findServiceProvider(FactoryFinder.java:305)
    at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:261)
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(DocumentBuilderFactory.java:140)
    at io.cdap.cdap.common.conf.Configuration.asXmlDocument(Configuration.java:1870)
    at io.cdap.cdap.common.conf.Configuration.writeXml(Configuration.java:1846)
    at io.cdap.cdap.app.runtime.spark.SparkRuntimeService.saveCConf(SparkRuntimeService.java:908)
    at io.cdap.cdap.app.runtime.spark.SparkRuntimeService.startUp(SparkRuntimeService.java:334)
    ... 3 common frames omitted
```

I have created Custom `CDAP` plugin to handle schema validation and tested it in `CDAP` local.

As a next step I would want this plugin to be tested in `GCP CDF` instance but it ended up with the error as stated above.

P.S: I have used CDAP version 6.9.2 and tested the CDF pipeline on Dedicated Dataproc Cluster (Pre-Existing Dataproc Cluster)

Answer (score 0):

Which version of CDAP are you using to test the plugin ? Also, which Dataproc profile are you using on the GCP CDF instance ?

Comment: Hello Ganesh, Thanks for the response. I have used CDAP 6.9.2 and tested it on dedicated dataproc cluster.

Comment: Hi Rajiv, are you using a custom dataproc image on the dedicated cluster ? The error seems to be caused by some issue with classloading.